# Submit button in react form not submitting

Tags: reactjs, form-submit, formik

I am trying to make a registration form using React.js and Formik. My submit button displays correctly but when I try to submit the information by clicking on the submit button nothing happens. Please advise how I can fix this. Thanks in advance.

RegistrationForm.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import FormikControl from './FormikControl';
import classes from './Registration.module.css';

function Registrationform() {
  const options = [
    { key: 'Email', value: 'emailmoc' },
    { key: 'Telephone', vlaue: 'telephonemoc' }
  ];

  const initialValues = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    modeOfContact: '',
    phone: ''
  };

  const validationSchema = yup.object({
    email: yup.string().email('Invalid email format').required('Required'),
    password: yup.string().required('Required'),
    confirmPassword: yup
      .string()
      .oneOf([yup.ref('password'), ''], 'Passwords must match')
      .required('required'),
    modeOfContact: yup.string().required('Required'),
    phone: yup.string().when('modeOfContact', {
      is: 'telephonemoc',
      then: yup.string().required('Required')
    })
  });

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log('Form data', values);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Registration</h1>

      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        {(formik) => {
          return (
            <Form className={classes.Registrationform}>
              <FormikControl
                control="input"
                type="email"
                label="Email"
                name="email"
              />

              <FormikControl
                control="input"
                type="password"
                label="Password"
                name="password"
              />

              <FormikControl
                control="input"
                type="password"
                label="Confirm Password"
                name="confirmPassword"
              />

              <FormikControl
                control="input"
                type="text"
                label="Phone number"
                name="phone"
              />

              <label>Mode of Contact</label>

              <div className="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" value="Phone" options={options} />
                  Phone
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" value="Email" options={options} />
                  Email
                </label>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" disabled={!formik.isValid}>
                Submit
              </button>
            </Form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Registrationform;
```

Registration.module.css:

```
  .Registrationform{
        margin:auto;
        padding-top: 50px;
        width:360px;
         
    }
    
    .Registrationform > label {
     
        font-weight: bold;
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
       
        font-size: 18px;
      }
      
      .Registrationform > input  {
       margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline-flex;
        margin-right: 20px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        outline:none;
        border: none;
        border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
       
      }
    
    
      .Registrationform > button{
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 425px;
        height: 35px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        outline:none;
        border: none;
        border: 1px solid #1E90FF;
        background-color: #1E90FF;
        color: white;
        font-size: 18px;
    
      }
    
      h1{
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
      }
```

FormikContainer:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import FormikControl from './FormikControl';

function FormikContainer() {
  const initialValues = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };
  const validationschema = Yup.object({
    email: Yup.string().required('Required')
  });
  const onSubmit = (values) => console.log('Form data', values);

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationschema={validationschema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        {(formik) => (
          <Form>
            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="email"
              label="Email"
              name="email"
            />

            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="password"
              label="Password"
              name="password"
            />

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormikContainer;
```

FormikControl:

```
import React from 'react';

function FormikControl({ control, id, label, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <>
      {control === 'input' && <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>}
      <input id={id} {...rest} />
    </>
  );
}

export default FormikControl;
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import FormikContainer from './components/FormikContainer';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import Registrationform from './components/RegistrationForm';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <LoginForm />
      <Registrationform />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `handleSubmit` function of formik to `Form` `onSubmit` event listener.

add the onSubmit prop to the `Form` as below

```
   <Form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
```

Or change your button code to (This approach is not mentioned in the formik doc)

```
    <button disabled={!formik.isValid} onClick={formik.handleSubmit}>
                Submit
    </button>
```

Here is more on [Form](https://formik.org/docs/api/form) API and [handleSubmit](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#handlesubmit-e-reactformeventhtmlformelement--void)

#### **Update**

With respect to the @malik-hassam's answer:

You are missing the password field in validation schema.

```
  const validationschema = Yup.object({
    email: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    password: Yup.string(),
  });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I tried both suggestions but it is still not submitting the form

Comment: Please check the update in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I added the password validation in FormikContainer but still does not submit. I also tried adding all the other validations from the RegistrationForm.js file but it still does not submit

Comment: Can you please create a minimal solution in codesandbox with your code?

Answer (score 0):

There is missing password validation.

```
    const LoginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string()
      .email("Email must be a valid email address")
      .required("Email is required"),
    password: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
  });
```

try use this.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the example. I tried it but my button still does not submit. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Pls find your code working demo here [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cartwright-drtznx?file=/src/App.js) and same as you can do for login component

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

function Registrationform() {
  const initialValues = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
    modeOfContact: "email",
    phone: ""
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email format").required("Required"),
    password: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string().oneOf(
      [Yup.ref("password"), null],
      "Passwords must match"
    ),
    modeOfContact: Yup.string().required("Required"),
    phone: Yup.string().matches(/^[6-9]\d{9}$/, {
      message: "Please enter valid number."
    })
  });

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log("Form data", values);
  };

  function FormikControl({ control, id, label, ...rest }) {
    return (
      <>
        {control === "input" && <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>}
        <input id={id} {...rest} />
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Registration</h1>

      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
        {({
          handleChange,
          errors,
          touched,
          handleBlur,
          values,
          isValid,
          dirty
        }) => (
          <Form className="Registrationform">
            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="email"
              label="Email"
              name="email"
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.email}
            />
            {errors.email && touched.email && errors.email}
            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="password"
              label="Password"
              name="password"
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.password}
            />
            {errors.password && touched.password && errors.password}
            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="password"
              label="Confirm Password"
              name="confirmPassword"
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.confirmPassword}
            />
            {errors.confirmPassword &&
              touched.confirmPassword &&
              errors.confirmPassword}
            <FormikControl
              control="input"
              type="text"
              label="Phone number"
              name="phone"
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.phone}
            />
            {errors.phone && touched.phone && errors.phone}

            <label>Mode of Contact</label>

            <div className="custom-control">
              <input
                id="email"
                type="radio"
                value="email"
                name="modeOfContact"
                onChange={handleChange}
                defaultChecked={values.modeOfContact === "email"}
              />
              <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="email">
                email
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="custom-control">
              <input
                id="phone"
                type="radio"
                value="phone"
                name="modeOfContact"
                onChange={handleChange}
                defaultChecked={values.modeOfContact === "phone"}
              />
              <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="phone">
                phone
              </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" disabled={!(isValid && dirty)}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Registrationform;
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. When I code the link from sandbox, it opens the react browser and the form displays and the submit works. When I use your code instead of mine in my RegistrationForm.js file the submit button still does not work

Comment: @Lizzy can you pls create sandbox link so i can help more

Comment: I am new to React and have not used Sandbox before. I'm getting a lot of errors in Sandbox that I do not get in my console. Think I am adding the code wrong in sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-tamas-4d9l6w?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @Lizzy i updated sandbox link pls follow same [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cartwright-drtznx?file=/src/LoginForm.js)

Comment: I tried to copy and paste your code from sandbox but my submit button still does not work. It actually displays a grey submit button that can't be clicked

Comment: pls add validate data in form it's enable automatically.

Comment: Hi Kanti, I am not sure what validating data to add because I thought I already had it added. Please can you give an example

Comment: @Lizzy you can fill the form like that PWD and confirm pwd should be the same [link](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/2022-07-11_15-36.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes let me add an example of code. you can use this.

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-form-validation-uog4g?file=/src/ValidatedLoginForm.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Emailvalidator from "email-validator";
import * as Yup from "yup";
const ValidatedLoginForm = () => (
  <>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        console.log(values);
        console;
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
          .email()
          .required("Email Required"),
        password: Yup.string()
          .required("Password Required")
          .min(8, "Password is Too short")
          .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Must Contain Number")
      })}
    >
      {props => {
        const {
          values,
          touched,
          errors,
          isSubmitting,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit
        } = props;
        return (
          <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input
                name="email"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                value={values.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                className={errors.email && touched.email && "error"}
              />
              {errors.email && touched.email && (
                <div className="input feedback">{errors.email}</div>
              )}
              <label htmlFor="email">Password</label>
              <input
                name="password"
                type="password"
                placeholder="Enter your password"
                value={values.password}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                className={errors.password && touched.password && "error"}
              />
              {errors.password && touched.password && (
                <div className="input feedback">{errors.password}</div>
              )}
              <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
                Login
              </button>
            </form>
          </>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  </>
);

export default ValidatedLoginForm;
```